# Handler class if lead is created or updated then check the email of lead is already there in existing contacts then through an error

Tags: apex, trigger

```java
trigger DuplicateEmailsInLead on Lead (before insert, before update) {
    map<String,Contact>  mapOfContact = new map<String, Contact>();
    list<Contact> con = [select id,email from contact];
    for (contact c:con) {
        mapofcontact.put(c.email,c);
    }
    for(lead l : trigger.new) {
        if((l.email != null) && (trigger.isInsert || (l.email != trigger.oldmap.get(l.id).email))) {
            if(mapofContact.containsKey(l.email)){
                l.Email.addError('Email already exists');
            }
        }               
    }
}
```

How to write trigger & handler Class for this

///////////////////////
This is what i tried
///////////////////////

### Handler:

```java
public class Handler_checkiftheemail {
    public static void TriggerHandler(List<Lead> newLeadList,map<string,contact> oldmapcontacts){
        map<String,Contact>  mapOfContact = new map<String, Contact>();
        list<Contact> con = [select id,email from contact];
        for (contact c:con){
            mapOfContact.put(c.email,c);
        }
        for(lead l :newLeadList){
            if((l.email != null) && (trigger.isInsert || (l.email != oldmapcontacts.get(l.id).email))){
                if(mapofContact.containsKey(l.email)){
                    l.Email.addError('Email already exists');
                }                  
            }               
        }
    }
}
```

### Trigger:

```java
trigger checkiftheemail on Lead (before insert,before update) {  
    
    if(trigger.isinsert && trigger.isupdate){
        Handler_checkiftheemail.TriggerHandler(Trigger.new,Trigger.oldMap);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Sai, and welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to read about [ask] and take the [tour]. Notably, this question has been asked and answered many times before here. Please feel free to use our [search tool](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/search) to find plenty of examples. I've also linked one example that should be pretty close to what you're looking for. Please let us know if you need further assistance. if you feel the other answers somehow don't answer your question, please feel free to [edit] to include more information, and let us know, we'll be glad to reopen your question.

Comment: Hy there @sfdcfox thanks for Acknowledging am looking for a handler class and yes there are some same trigger but here my doubt is not on the trigger but the handler class

Comment: Sai, please do take some time to review the resources sfdcfox linked and make sure that each of your posts fits the format described in [ask] and [help/on-topic]. We are almost always going to ask you to show us what you've done (that's good, here), and where you're stuck - your post should contain a specific question to the community.

Answer (score 1):

Your trigger logic confused "and" with "or." You will never be in an insert AND an update trigger at the same time, so you need to use OR instead:

```
if(trigger.isinsert || trigger.isupdate){
```

That said, this is not necessary. The trigger will only fire on the correct events (before insert, before update).

```
trigger checkiftheemail on Lead (before insert,before update) {  
  Handler_checkiftheemail.TriggerHandler(Trigger.new,Trigger.oldMap);
}
```

Please be aware that your trigger handler class is currently query the entire database every time you create or update a record. This will create governor limit problems later.

You need to use the [aggregate-query-update](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/search?q=aggregate%20query%20update%20pattern) pattern to first check for emails on incoming leads, then query the contacts, and then add errors on duplicate leads.

Also note that [Leads are not Contacts](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/295715/2984). If you're trying to use them that way, you're probably missing the point of leads. In fact, in a good system, 80% of your Leads *should* already be existing contacts. This is the Pareto principle in action, where 80% of your business would ordinarily be repeat customers. unless you're selling houses or something big.

You might want to [automatically convert the leads into contacts](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/44771/2984) instead, which would give you valuable marketing and ROI information you'll be missing out on if you outright block those records from coming in.